# PermissionsAndroid for iOS in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, ios-permissions

I use this code to get user permission in android

```
async componentWillMount() {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
}
```

How to use this for `ios`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library used only with android , Use Third party library Like :
https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions